# Convert Excel equation to Python equation for 2d list

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7

I need to convert a string of Excel equation to a python code so it can bracket into a 2d list and give me the answer. In this scenario, the columns are named using a letter (A to Z) and rows are named (1 to 26). So, for example, what I have is:

```
list = [[1,1],
        [1,1]]
```

the string is:

```
my_str = "=A2 + 1"
```

and I need to convert it to:

```
list[1][0] + 1
```

or another example:

```
my_str = "=B2 + A2"
```

convert to:

```
list[1][1] + list[1][0]
```

Note that because of the way columns and rows are named, I need to switch the letter and the number, so A2 would be 2A and then [1][0].

I have spent hours trying to figure this out with no luck. any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: you'll need an expression evaluator for that in the end. not trivial.

Comment: OTOH, converting a cell name string like `'A2'` into a pair of indices like (1, 0) is fairly trivial.

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of automated tool (e.g., X2C) that knows how to map Excel onto variables in source code.

Answer (score 0):

my solution may be little long but it effective specially in non complex equations in complex equation will be more hard

First to convert cell reference to 2d Array use:

```
="list[" & ROW(INDIRECT("A1"))-1 & "][" & COLUMN(INDIRECT("A1"))-1 & "]"
```

if your range start from other cell not "A1" subtract its row and column from each term
then list all references you used in equations and use this equation to convert them
next step to use find() to detect if the reference name is exist in equation and replace it if it exist
[image]

the full equations
[image]

notice the equation is converted to text frist by add =" at begin and " at the end
and  in second row to the end I used the upper cell to convert the next term